# nested ng-repeat - displaying model based another model

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "data in tabularData">
    <td ng-repeat="column in allColumns">{{ data.{{column}} }}</td>         
</tr>
```

I am trying to get data based off the set of column data.  I might be looking at this at the wrong angle.  The reason I have a different model for columns is because it varies depending on the data and I let the user control which columns to see (I could just hide them but we're keen on performance).

Comment: And what do you get? It will be easier to help if you provide the contents of the `tabularData` and `allColumns` JSONs.

Answer (score 2):

Close man, you need bracket notation!

```
<td ng-repeat="column in allColumns">{{ data[column] }}</td>
```

And since you're already writing in an Angular expression - no need to double wrap the curly braces.